# WPF - Getting a collection of all controls for a given type on a Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, find

I'm trying to get a list of all controls of a given type on a given Page, but I'm encountering problems.  It seems that it's possible that the VisualTreeHelper only returns controls that have been loaded?  I tried turning off Virtualization, but that didn't seem to help.  Can anyone think of another way to get all the control or perhaps force a load of the UI so that the following method does work?

I borrowed this from MSDN:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using `FlowDocuments` and so on in the `Page`?

Comment: Nope.  Just a series of UIElements.  The real problem I'm having is getting the specific controls I seek from my TabControl.  Only the first TabItem seems to return anything.  I'd assumed a Virtualization problem as the code is being called during the Load event for the page and only the first TabItem is "visible".

Comment: I suspect that the `TabControl` might be reusing the `TabItem` template, just changing the content of it when you switch tabs. If you change the tab, do you get another set of controls back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the following thread: [Finding all controls of a given type across a TabControl](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/693abf03-5042-4ab6-86e8-76aa24a496e9/)

The answer from *Tao Liang* is a good explanation

> The reason is that the WPF designer want to optimize the performance
>   of TabControl. Suppose there are 5 TabItems, and each TabItem contains
>   alot of children. If WPF program have to construct and render all the
>   children, it will be very slow. But if TabControl only handle the
>   children just in the current selected TabItem, much memory will be
>   saved.

You can give the logical tree a try instead.
Here is an example implementation of this, see if it works better for you

*Use it like this..*

```
List<Button> buttons = GetLogicalChildCollection<Button>(yourPage);
```

*GetLogicalChildCollection*

```
public static List<T> GetLogicalChildCollection<T>(object parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    List<T> logicalCollection = new List<T>();
    GetLogicalChildCollection(parent as DependencyObject, logicalCollection);
    return logicalCollection;
}
private static void GetLogicalChildCollection<T>(DependencyObject parent, List<T> logicalCollection) where T : DependencyObject
{
    IEnumerable children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent);
    foreach (object child in children)
    {
        if (child is DependencyObject)
        {
            DependencyObject depChild = child as DependencyObject;
            if (child is T)
            {
                logicalCollection.Add(child as T);
            }
            GetLogicalChildCollection(depChild, logicalCollection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what will be the value of the 'yourpage'? I want to access all the buttons in current window.