# is it possible to list all xaml image tags in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

Is there any way to get a list of all xaml  tags (or any other tag) in c# in windows phone without giving them names?

Something like :

```
var list = this.GetElementsByTagName("Image");
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153248/wpf-getting-a-collection-of-all-controls-for-a-given-type-on-a-page

Comment: This may help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
foreach(UIElement item in YourContainer.Children){
    MessageBox.Show(item.GetType().ToString());
}
```

It will return something like `System.Window.Control.Image`